# Worksheet not displayed in VBE Microsoft Excel Objects

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I got a workbook from my colleague and I can see a worksheet in the regular Excel interface, but when I open VBE, I found that the worksheet is not displayed under

`Project window>VBAProject (ThisWorkbook's name)>Microsoft Excel Objects`.

Are the worksheet object hidden somehow in the VBE?

Comment: Is it a "regular" worksheet?  special worksheets (eg. a vb4 Macro Sheet, a VB 5 dialog sheet) won't show in the VBA IDE.  If you right-click on it and the "view code" option is greyed-out, it is probably an Excel 4 Macro Sheet.

Comment: @ainwood This is beyond my knowledge, is there a way I can know the type of this sheet, like any code I can use in immediate window and get back to you with the result maybe? I do know the name of the sheet, though (as I can see from the regular Excel interface).

Comment: @ainwood FYI, if I select this sheet, `TypeName(ActiveSheet)` only gives me `Worksheet` in immediate window

Comment: Your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959503/cannot-find-the-vba-macro-assigned-to-the-button-in-excel) suggests that this is indeed a Macro Sheet, not a worksheet, hence it is not visible in the IDE.  You could migrate the code to the - will need to modify it, but it is probably a good idea for the future.

Answer (score 0):

It may be ae Excel 4 Macro Sheet or an Excel 4 International Macro Sheet.  These things look just like worksheets, and if they are the Activesheet, the TypeName will still return 'worksheet'.  However, they don't behave like a worksheet - if you (say) put `=A1*5` in cell B1, it will just appear as text.

You can list all of these macro sheets in the IDE by enumerating the relevant collections:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ListObjects()
Dim oMacroSheet As Object

'//Find all Excel4MacroSheets
Debug.Print "------- Excel 4 Macro Sheets ----------"
For Each oMacroSheet In ThisWorkbook.Excel4MacroSheets
    Debug.Print oMacroSheet.Name
Next oMacroSheet


    '//Find all Excel4InternationalMacroSheets
    Debug.Print "------- Excel 4 International Macro Sheets ----------"
    For Each oMacroSheet In ThisWorkbook.Excel4IntlMacroSheets
        Debug.Print oMacroSheet.Name
    Next oMacroSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: I see you used `Dim oMacroSheet As Object` rather than` Dim oMacroSheet As Worksheet`, is there any reason?

Comment: Simply because I wasn't sure if a Excel4MacroSheet object inherits from WorkSheet or not.  A `For Each` can give you an error if you try to use `for each` of one object type on a collection that is of a different type.  Using `object` makes it a bit more tolerant of problems (but could have caused a separate issue if there was no `name` property, but most things do have a Name property.