# Cannot find the VBA macro assigned to the button in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I got a workbook from someone else, and there is a button assigned with a macro (since I can right click and choose `Assign Macro` to actually see the macro name).

However, I cannot find this macro in any Modules inside VBE as well as the code window behind ThisWorkbook and any Sheet (so it's not an event). In addition, I found that after I clicked `Assign Macro` option from right-click menu, I was switched to another worksheet that has several cells that looks like this,

[image]

But it looks to me that those formula are not from `WorksheetFunction`. Is the button really associated with a VBA macro or if this is just something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an XLM sheet, the "pre-VBA" way of writing macros:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Working-with-Excel-4-0-macros-ba8924d4-e157-4bb2-8d76-2c07ff02e0b8